Cocycles and the Collatz problem?
Let $T(n) = n+R(n)$, where $R(n) = -n/2 $ if $n\equiv 0 \mod 2$ else $R(n) = \frac{n+1}{2}$.
$R(n)$ is the Cantor ordering of the integers:
https://oeis.org/A001057
In the Collatz problem, one is interested in the parity vector $x(n)$ of $n$:
$$x_k(n) : = T^k(n) \mod(2)$$
It is easy to see, that iterations of $R$ map each integer to either $0=R(0)$ or $1=R(1)$.
2-Cocycles:
Define
$$\epsilon_k(a,b):= T^k(a+b)-T^k(a)-T^k(b)\mod(2)$$
Then $\epsilon_k: \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$ is a 2-cocycle for each $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$:
This can be proven because the addition in $\mathbb{Z}$ is associative:
$$T^k(a+(b+c))  = T^k((a+b)+c)$$
1. Question:
Is it true that for $k \ge2$:
$$T^k(n) \equiv \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} R^i(n) + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-i-1} \epsilon_i(R^j(n),R^{j+1}(n)) \binom{k-i-1}{j} \mod(2)$$?
Edit 07.07.2024:
This can be proven by induction on $k$.
On the right hand side, we see only iterations of $R$, denoted as $R^i,R^j$. But then for large enough $k$ we  have $R^l(n) = R^k(n) = 0 \text{ or } 1$ for $l \ge k$.
Hence maybe this might give a hint as to why the parity vector of each natural number repeats with $0,1$ after some time (Collatz conjecture).
I am not saying that it proves the Collatz conjecture.
2. question:
What other applications of cohomology could be applied in this situation?
Here is some Sagemath Code for experimentation:
def TT(m):
    if m%2==0:
        return m//2
    else:
        return (3*m+1)//2
    
def R(n):
    if n%2==0:
        return -n//2
    else:
        return (n+1)//2

def iterFunc(func,k,n):
    if k==0:
        return n
    else:
        return func(iterFunc(func,k-1,n))
    
    
def Tk(k,n):
    return iterFunc(TT,k,n)

def Rk(k,n):
    return iterFunc(R,k,n)

def eps(a,b,base=2,k=1):
    return (Tk(k,a+b)-(Tk(k,a)+Tk(k,b)))%base
    

def rhs(k,n):
    if k>=2:
        return (sum(binomial(k,i)*Rk(i,n) for i in range(k+1))+sum(sum(eps(Rk(j,n),Rk(j+1,n),base=2,k=i)*binomial(k-i-1,j) for j in range(k-i-1+1)) for i in range(1,k-1+1)))%2
    

for n in range(1,100):
    for k in range(2,15):
        print(n,k,Tk(k,n)%2==rhs(k,n))

Edit:
Let $I(n)$ denote the stopping time when the starting number $n$ iterates to either $0$ or $1$ under $R$:
$$I(n) := \min_{R^i(n) \in \{0,1\}} \{i\}$$
Then by empirical observation for $n=1,\cdots,10^5$ I think that:
$$T^{I(n)^3}(n) \in \{1,2\}$$

11 edits so far.  Each one bumps the question to the top of the queue, so it is considered inappropriate to make frequent edits to a question.  On the mathematical side, I can assure you that you won't make progress on deep questions like the Collatz conjecture with elementary observations like this.

@AndyPutman the "elemental observations" seem to be offered as a demonstration of the applicability of cohomology to the subject matter, as a preface to asking those who know more about cohomology, to suggest how else it might be appled.  That can then be used by the OP to direct their studies.  Is it not a bit disingenuous to then reply as if the initial "elemental observation" is the upper limit on their efforts?
